# Proof verification of set equalities about functions and union/intersection

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

I want some verification of my arguments for proving the two set equalities below. First a definition: given any set $A$, let $P(A)$ denote the set of all subsets of $A$.

> Consider a function $f:P(A)\to P(A)$ such that, for any $X,Y\subset A$,
>
> (i): $X\subset Y \implies f(Y) \subset f(X)$
>
> (ii): $f(f(X)) = X$
>
> Show that $f(\cup X_{\lambda}) = \cap f(X_{\lambda})$ and $f(\cap X_{\lambda}) = \cup f(X_{\lambda})$

My attempt: For each $X\in P(A)$, we can treat $X$ as a (singleton) subset of $P(A)$ so we can use the usual properties of image. Then if $X\subset Y \implies f(Y)\subset f(X)$, using the fact that $f(X)\subset f(Y)$, we have $f(X) = f(Y)$ and applying (ii) we have $X = Y$. Therefore $$X\subset Y \implies X = Y, \forall X,Y\in P(A).$$ Then, once $\cap f(X_{\lambda})\subset \cup f(X_{\lambda}) = f(\cup X_{\lambda})$, we have $f(\cup X_{\lambda}) = \cap f(X_{\lambda})$, the first equality.

Now, from $\cap f(X_{\lambda})\supset f(\cap X_{\lambda})$ we have $f(\cup X_{\lambda}) \supset f(\cap X_{\lambda})$, from where follows the second equality: $f(\cup X_{\lambda}) = \cap f(X_{\lambda})\quad\quad\quad \square$

I'm somewhat concerned with the argument of using the subsets of $A$ as subsets of $P(A)$ and applying the properties of images. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you really mean $f(Y) = f(X)$ in (i)? If so then $f(Y) = f(\emptyset)$ for any $Y$ and so $f(X) = f(Y)$ for any $X$ and $Y$.

Comment: It's $f(Y) \subset f(X)$, I'll correct it. Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean  $\subset$ or $\subseteq$?

Comment: I think $\subset$ is being used in the text of the question (it was not made by me) in a way that it does not exclude the possibility of $=$.

Comment: It is not a fact that f(X) subset f(Y).

Comment: I used $X\subset Y \Rightarrow f(X) \subset f(Y)$.

Comment: Why can you use that?  It was not given as part of the problem.

Comment: It was listed as a property of functions and subsets of their domains. I imagine there's something wrong because it would imply that every subset of A is empty, but I can't find exactly where is the mistake.

Comment: Take a look at my answer to see why A is empty is wrong.  You mistake was the unwarrented assumption f(X) = f(Y).

Comment: @NoGoodAtMath.  That is not about functions whose domain is P(X).  It is about extending a function f from a domain  X to all of the subsets K, of X with f[K] = { f(x) : x in K }, a special construction used  to notate images of a function.  In otherwords, it does not apply!

Answer (score 0):

Theroems for the above system.
For all X,Y subset A, (X = Y iff f(X) = f(Y)).
For all X,Y subset A, (X = f(Y) iff f(X) = Y).
f(empty set) = A; empty set = f(A).
Proofs are simple.  Is f the A-complement operator?